# How to Print a square with asterisks in java with while loop only?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I would like to know how to print a square with asterisks in java with a `while` loop only 
but with out `for` loop and with out any logic operations like: **AND** or **OR**

This code should do something like that: if we enter `4` it should print:

```
* * * *
*     *
*     *
* * * *
```

but it does some thing else, like that:

```
* **


*
```

---

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int squareside ;
    System.out.print("Enter the side: ");
    squareside = input.nextInt();

    while ( squareside != -1 )
    {
        int xaxis = 0 ;
        while ( xaxis < squareside )
        {

            if( xaxis == 0 ) {
                System.out.print(" *") ;
            }
            else if( xaxis == squareside - 1){
                System.out.print(" *") ;
            }
            else
                System.out.print(" ") ;

            xaxis ++ ;

        }
        int yaxis = 0 ;

        while( yaxis < squareside )
        {
            if( yaxis == 0 )
            { 
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            else if( yaxis == squareside - 1)

            {
                System.out.print(" *");
            }
            else    
                System.out.print(" ");  

            yaxis ++;
            System.out.println();

        }

        System.out.print("Enter the side: ");
        squareside = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing you can do with a `for` loop that you can't do with a `while` loop.  `for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)` ==> `int x = 0; while (x < a) { x++; rest of loop`

Comment: And think about how you'd do it:  Draw the top line, then loop to draw the N-2 identical middle lines, then draw the bottom line.  Don't put the top and bottom lines in the main loop.

Comment: @HotLicks Almost good. More precisely: `for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)` translates to `int x = 0; while (x < a) { ...rest of loop;  x++; }` -- note that `x++` happens at the end of the loop.

Comment: @GaborSch - Yep, one of those "minor details" that can bite you.

Answer (score 1):

quick and verbose, but should work. It does not use `if` or anything else except `while` loop. Feel free to optimize :

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    // logic :
    // print first line * * * *
    // print the rest of lines *      * in a loop
    // print last line * * * *

    int len = 5; // user input
    int x = 0;

    // print first line
    while (x++ < len) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println(); // new line
    // print the rest of lines *      * in a loop
    x = 0;
    while (x++ < len - 2) {
        System.out.print('*'); // beginning of line
        int y = 0;
        while (y++ < len - 2) {
            System.out.print("  "); // dobule spaces
        }
        System.out.println(" *"); // end of line
    }
    x = 0;
    // print the last line
    while (x++ < len) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3043998 what do you mean by that ? the user input ? just copy your code for reading input with scanner.

Comment: @user3043998 like Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter the side: ");
     int len = input.nextInt(); // instead of int len = 5;

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter the size of the side of a square: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = input.nextInt();
        String re1 = repeat1("*", num);
        String re2 = repeat2("*", num);
        System.out.println(re1);
        System.out.print(re2);
        System.out.print(re1);

    }


    public static String spaces(int i) //Repeat space
    {
        String spaces = "";
        for (int j = 1; j <= (2 * i - 3); j++) //(2 * i - 3) : for exrta space between Asterisks on Top and bottom side
        {
            spaces = spaces + " ";
        }
        return spaces;
    }


    public static String repeat1(String s, int i) //Top and bottom side
    {
        String tst = "";
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            tst = s + " " + tst;
        }
        return tst;
    }


    public static String repeat2(String s, int i) // Left and right side
    {
        spaces(i);
        String tst1 = "";

        for (int j = 1; j <= i - 2; j++)
        {
            tst1 = s + spaces(i) + s + "\n" + tst1;
        }

        return tst1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't just paste code but also explain what you have done and why it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution to the problem. Spaces can be easily added between asterisks, if needed:

```
   // Square.java
   // Create a hollow square of asterisks.
   // The side size is entered by the user 
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Square
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        int row = 1;
        int column = 1;
        int side;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the size of the square side: ");
        side = input.nextInt();

        while (row <= side)
        {
            column = 1;
            System.out.print("*");
            while (column <= (side - 2))
            {
                System.out.print(row == 1 || row == side ? "*" : " ");
                ++column;
            }
            ++row;
            System.out.printf("*%n");
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can notice that you have to print stars only on the border values. That is when (x or y) is 0 or (x or y) is equal to squareside-1.

```
for (int x=0; x < squareside; ++x) {
    for (int y=0; y < squareside; ++y)
        if (x == 0 || x+1 == squareside ||
            y == 0 || y+1 == squareside) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: OP asked for while loop only